# react get specific object to a multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a question / issue
i have a array of users and i want to get specific user from the sign up page
so this one is easy it mean that i need to run at filter and get the specific user
the problem i have this function and send it to the sign in components
but i need this specific user in multiple components
how i can save this user and send it back
i can use usestate that will contain this specific user but i dont think its the correct approch
what that i do is call the specificUser function on every componente that needed for this user but it mean that i need to get the username and password every time and its a lot of work

```
  const specificUser = (username, password) => {
    const check = users.find((user) => {
      return user.username === username && user.password === password;
    });
    return check;
  };

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Authentication from "../../components/authentication_sign/AuthenticationSign";
import { useDataProvider } from "../../context/Data";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const SignInPage = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { specificUser } = useDataProvider();
  const handleClick = (data) => {
    const { username, password } = data;
    if (username === "Admin" && password === "1111") return navigate("/admin");
    if (!specificUser(username, password)) return setError("user not found");
    navigate("/user/current-account", { state: specificUser(username, password) });
  };
  return <Authentication userError={error} onClick={handleClick} text={"sign in"} />;
};

export default SignInPage;
```

Comment: It depends. You can use a [context](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or you can simply pass the user via props all the way down to where it's needed

Comment: i using context api i forgot to add this on this code
all the data come from the context api and i wrap it
like you can see the function specificUser is in the context api and it mean i can send it to every components that i want
the problem this function get 2 parameter username and password and i need them on every components 
and it make me to repeat myself for nothing i am sure there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why are you handling the user on client Side.

Also, i would like to suggest you another way of checking for the user credentials.

use an Object instead of an Array.

With Array.find() you are checking  on each array index to look for the user you want.
If you use an Object instead of the array, you could get directly to the user you want.

```
const userList = {
   "userName1": {
      password: '123'
    },
   "userName2": {
      password: '324' 
   }
}
```

this way you can access to the user you want as simple as `userList["userName"]` and the complexity will be O(1), while that "Array" find has O(n).

In javascript. Arrays, are nothing than a numerical ordered Objects.

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

is the same as

```
const obj = {
   "0": "a",
   "1": "b",
   "2": "c"
}
```

Example => You can try this code on: https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yjp383ke

```
const userList = {
   "userName1": {
       id: "23423425",
       name: "person1",
       password: '123'
    },
   "userName2": {
       id: "23423426",
       name: "person2",
      password: '324' 
   }
}


const specificUser = (username, password) => {
    if(username in userList && userList[username].password === password ) return userList[username]
    else console.log('no user with these credentials') // undefined will be return, handle yourself
}


console.log(specificUser("userName1", "123"))
```

Comment: so in this approch i will take the users[usernameState] ?
usernameState will be the set usernameState on the sign in components

Comment: Yes, you could first check if the userName exists by  ` if(userName in users )  check password`

Comment: Ok i get it... but if i make this way its mean that i will create 2 state one for the username and one for the password because i need to check both of them so it still a good approch? Because we dont need to use a lot of states. .

Comment: it wouldnt change anything, you are only changing your users  structure from an array to a object

Comment: I have edited my original post with example

Comment: thank you for you time.
yeah i saw this and understand this but i have another problem with this approch
you use function to get the specific user
if i have a multiple components  that all in app.js and 5 of them need this specific user details
this function need 2 parameter
so it mean that on every components i need to pass this specificUser function and username + password
i want to avoid it because its make me to repeat myself in the code
how can i use this function specificUser that get 2 parameter and call it once and pass the object to all the components that i need?

Comment: create another Context for Auth purpose, and save the user credentials there. this video might help you. [Context](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LrDIWkK_Bc)